# NSMetadataQuery with .Trash folder brings no results

Tags: cocoa

I'm trying to implement a class which uses a NSMetadataQuery to find objects within a specified location. I tried it with the user's Downloads folder and the user's .Trash folder. Querying the Downloads folder works find but the query for the .Trash folder always return 0 results (though there are files in it).

I'm creating an NSPredicate with the value of

```
((kMDItemDisplayName != \"*\"))
```

and the search scope

```
/Users/xyz/.Trash
```

But that doesn't work. Using the search scope

```
/Users/xyz/Downloads
```

works fine.

I have read that Spotlight may ignore invisible files. So I created a second predicate with

```
kMDItemFSInvisible == YES
```

and combined them both to an NSCompoundPredicate with an "AndPredicateType". But this doesn't work as well (neither works "OrPredicateType").

Does anybody have a clue?

Just to mention: I'm using Swift with Xcode 6 Beta 5, but I think that doesn't matter.

**Edit**

The reason for this all: I want to find ALL items within a specified folder. I could use NSFileManager... but retrieving file information from it is a pain (incredibly slow when retrieving the attributes file by file).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on Apple's documentation it doesn't seem to be possible to use NSMetadataQuery for querying the Trash folder:

> Note: It is important to remember that on OS X, while file-system metadata is available on all volumes, other metadata attributes are not. CDs, DVDs, disk images and **System directories** are not indexed by Spotlight.